# Regarding to change the installation folder from %LocalAppData% to %ProgramFiles%

Tags: windows-7, installation

I didn't notice until I looked for Chrome that all my recently installed programs are being installed within `%LocalAppData%`, which is temporarily hidden by default, and when I tried to install a program and pick the browse folder, I couldn't choose `%ProgramFiles%` to install my program within. I want to change this thing for the sake of the system's regulations.

Comment: This depends, among other things, on the installer of the programs you are using. You may want to read https://superuser.com/questions/1445143/saving-data-program-files-vs-appdata-windows

Comment: Chrome has been installed to AppData for nearly a decade. Why couldn’t you install these unnamed application to Program Files? Are you not an Administrator? I see you’re running Windows 7. That likely is connected to this behavior.

Comment: Browsers have per user profiles, so they're installed to `%LocalAppData%` - per user applications are almost always installed within `%LocalAppData%` or `%AppData%`; this is expected behavior, as there are five program installation directories, each with their own purpose: `%ProgramFiles%`, `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`, `%ProgramData%`, `%LocalAppData%`, and `%AppData%`. What program is being installed and is its installer an `.msi` or `.exe`, and if executing the installer from a terminal with `/?`, `-?`, or `-h`, is any output returned _(would allow specifying install directory via cli)_?

Comment: @JW0914 applications can install to Program Files and still have per-user profiles where configuration and data files are stored in %LocalAppData% but the application executables are stored in Program Files. Applications installed to %LocalAddData% entirely are not only "per user profiles" but will also not be installed for other users on that computer. Some applications allow choosing a single user or all users install option, sometimes this is regardless whether they are run as administrator or not.